# How to serve shared struct with Go http package?

Tags: http, go, concurrency, go-templates

I have a struct with many fields (some of them are pointers to other structs as well) which are being continuosly updated in a separate goroutine. The same struct is accessed from go's `http` template when a page is served.

Code example:

```
type SharedStruct struct {
     Description string
     Counter int
     Status_ *Status
     LastChecked time.Time
     //other fields
} 
var shared = &SharedStruct{}

go func() {
    //..updates fields every 5 minutes
}()
```

go-http handler:

```
func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", shared)
}
```

and `page.html` template:

```
...
Status: {{.Status_.StatusCode}}
Counter: {{.Counter}}
Last checked: {{.LastChecked.Format "2006-02-01 15:04:05"}}
```

So far everything works as expected, but I'm aware that bad things can happen without any synchronization. What is the preferred way to handle this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred way is the same as in any other cases.

Either use a mutex when the shared struct is read / updated:

```
var shared = &SharedStruct{}
var mux = &sync.RWMutex{}

func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mux.RLock()
    defer mux.RUnlock()
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", shared)
}

// Code that modifies shared:
mux.Lock()
shared.Counter++
mux.Unlock()
```

Or if the template execution takes long time, it may be protitable to make a copy of the `shared` struct and pass the copy when executing the template, so that during template execution access to `shared` is not blocked. Note that while making the copy you still have to use a mutex. Also if not only the pointers but the pointed values may change, you also have to make a copy of those:

```
func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    mux.RLock()
    shared2 := &SharedStruct{}
    *shared2 = *shared
    shared2.Status_ = new(Status)
    *shared2.Status_ = *shared.Status_
    mux.RUnlock()

    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "page.html", shared2)
}
```

If the template only uses a small subset of the `shared` fields, it is enough to make only a copy of those of course.